# Does paralysis last through unconsciousness?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, healing, unconscious

My cleric was paralyzed by a yeti, then one shot critted to unconsciousness. If my comrade heals me, am I still under paralysis and required to make a Con saving throw? Or does the paralysis shake off after coming up to positive hit points?

Comment: Whoops! Noted for future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The Paralyzed condition lasts until a minute passes (or you pass the save); in general, conditions tell you when/how they end

The section on "[Conditions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions)" states:

> [...] A condition lasts either until it is countered (the prone condition is countered by standing up, for example) or **for a duration specified by the effect that imposed the condition.**

In this particular case the [Yeti](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/yeti)'s statblock states (I have assumed the Yeti's Chilling Gaze feature is what paralyzed you):

> ***Chilling Gaze.*** [...] The target must succeed on a DC 13 Constitution saving throw against this magic or take 10 (3d6) cold damage and then be paralyzed **for 1 minute**, unless it is immune to cold damage.

Unless something explicitly says otherwise, the paralyzed condition that Chilling Gaze causes will not end until the 1 minute is up; one such explicit exception is the [*lesser restoration*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/lesser-restoration) spell, which states:

> [...] You touch a creature and can end either one disease or one condition afflicting it. The condition can be blinded, deafened, paralyzed, or poisoned.

As user [@Ryan Thompson](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/40516/ryan-thompson) points out, there is further evidence that conditions persist even through the more extreme case of death. The [PHB errata](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) states:

> ***Exhaustion (p. 291).*** The following sentence is appended to the last paragraph: “Also, being raised from the dead reduces a creature’s exhaustion level by 1.”

There would be no reason to reduce a creature's exhaustion level upon resurrection unless death did not reduce it to 0 already. Thus exhaustion levels persist even through death, let alone just unconsciousness, this would similarly apply to other conditions as well.

---

It is noteworthy that while unconscious you would continue to make saving throws to end the paralysis from Chilling Gaze (if you wanted). This could end the effect before the 1 minute is up, and is possible because ending the Paralysis requires a Constitution saving throw -- both the Unconscious and Paralyzed conditions only make you automatically fail Strength and Dexterity saving throws.

Comment: Other evidence: exhaustion level (another condition) persists even through death (or else there would be no reason for resurrection to reduce exhaustion level by 1).

Comment: @RyanThompson Hopefully I've edited to include that in my answer